# Is there a relatively easy way for a hybrid .Net exe (console app/Windows service) to install and start itself as a service?

Tags: windows-services, .net-4.0, bootstrapping

Suppose an executable named `ConsoleOrService.exe` is written in `C#`. It currently is a hybrid. I can just start it on the command line, or I can install it using the .Net's `installutil ConsoleOrService.exe` and then start the service. I would like a third option: running it on the command line like so: `ConsoleOrService.exe  --install` and have it do all of the work.

1. Is this possible?
2. Is this hard?
3. How can I get started?

Thank you, and let me know if there are questions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually quite simple. I've used it in many of my own services (in fact, ALL of my services are capable of doing their own install/uninstall. I control it with a command-line switch, such as `/install` or `/uninstall`.

The installation is performed like this:

```
private static void InstallService()
{
 var ti  = new System.Configuration.Install.TransactedInstaller();
 var si  = new MyServiceInstaller();
 var cl  = new string[] { string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "/assemblypath={0}", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) };
 var ctx = new System.Configuration.Install.InstallContext(null, cl);

 ti.Installers.Add(si);
 ti.Context = ctx;
 ti.Install(new Hashtable());
}
```

The uninstallation is the same, except that you call `ti.Uninstall(null);` instead of `ti.Install(...);`.

My `MyServiceInstaller` is a class that inherits from the `System.Configuration.Install.Installer` class (as you would normally have in a service).

Comment: Nice, could you show us more details, for exemple how you handle the command line in program ?

Comment: I assume this is part of it, I am sure that all sorts of nasty exceptions come up. To echo Pierre, if you do not mind sharing some more code, that would be very welcomed.

Comment: My command line handling is nothing more complex than an `if( args.Length > 0 ) { ... }` and a `switch( args[0] ) { ... }` in this particular project. I don't handle any exceptions specially, because there is a global handler for `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` that does logging for me.